Paying for a flight when 'address line 3' is required
I'm trying to book a flight on British Airlines' website. My billing address is in the United States, but the form is prompting for a required Address Line 3:

My address looks something like this:
123 Main St             | Address Line 1
Apt 9                   | Address Line 2
Denver, CO 80201 USA    | City, State (abbr) Postal Code Country

The form won't let me leave Address Line 3 blank. I've tried putting a space, I've tried putting the city (Denver) since there is no other place to put it. But in all cases the form is rejected.
How can I go about paying for this flight?

to me it's clear you should put Denver there. What is the error message when you do?

The transaction is rejected, but with no additional details. I've confirmed with my bank that they're not declining the transaction -- it's something with the address validation that's going wrong. It basically kicks me back to the "flight search" and I have to start again.

I've recently hit a weird bug in the BA booking page, where it would not let me enter required data if I clicked on a field. When I hit the "pay" button, it would complain about the errors, and then let me put in the data in the fields it refused to before. It didn't send me back to the beginning though. My other half ran into the same problem, both were on standard issue Windows/Chrome/Firefox combinations.

Is debugging BA's shitty website really on-topic? Try booking through a partner airline, such as American Airlines, who will probably offer the same flights.

It's on topic because problems like "my country has addresses commonly in format A but foreign country service provider assumes format B, can I somehow get around this?" are common travel woes. We also take similar issues about phone numbers, postal codes, personal names ("I have no last name"), and so on.

Also funny enough this is a code share but the fare class I'm trying to buy seats with are only available through BA and not any other airline -- so use a partner site isn't an option here.

I've had a similar problem in the past, can't remember which website, but I successfully repeated the same text in Address Line 1 and Address Line 3

What does the button with 3 dots at right of Address line 1 do? I suspect it might open a picker that autofills the necessary fields as needed (also the same button on the Card number; if using a mobile device that can scan a card, I would, for example, expect it to fill the expiry date, too).

Hm, I always put the apartment number on the same line as the street, as in "123 Main St Apt 4E"

Computers have existed for a good while. Addresses, even longer. One would think that by now we would have a global formatting standard for addresses. But it turns out that things are complicated.

@user85471 the button with three dots is actually from a password manager plugin, offering to auto-fill the address for me; it's greyed out because I don't have any saved addresses. Similar with card number for the payment card above the address fields.

Since the line two is optional you could try to use line 3 instead, leaving line 2 blank:
123 Main St             | Address Line 1
Apt 9                   | Address Line 3
Denver, CO 80201 USA    | City, State (abbr) Postal Code Country

However, there's also the possibility that the payment is rejected for another reason (could even be a bug in their website). I would also suggest using an incognito browser window and/or a different browser.

I had a similar problem on another part of the BA web site. Using a different browser worked.

I have found there are sites that I can't buy stuff with in Google Chrome, but I can in Firefox or Opera.

This is a defect in their website and sometimes you have to use trial and error to try to fake it out.  It seems the developer left out City, which should be required, and instead made Address 3 required.
One solution is to try again later.  Hopefully the page will be fixed shortly. You can of course, call the company and inquire about this error.
In your case putting Apt 9 or Denver (from the comments) might work.  Logically they are good choices, but it is unclear how far the defect carries into the software.  There may not be a solution where you can pass acceptable information.  For example, the text box for address 3 might be assigned to a variable called "address3", and later the code checks for a value in variable "city".  If no value is found for "city" then an error is thrown.  You have no way to assign a value to "city" so no way to make payment.
